# Cannot go to new line from folded line

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, when I have my cursor after the three dots at the end of a headline whose subtree is folded and I press Return, the cursor does not go to the new line as expected. It simply stays where it is. I don't remember this happening until recently. Is there a setting for this? Example in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What does `M-x org-version` say? With the cursor as shown, what does `C-u C-x =` say? Finally what does `C-h c RET` say? When I press RET at the indicated place (which happens to be at the end of the buffer), I get the message "Edit in invisible region aborted, repeat to confirm with text visible"; it then unfolds the last headline with the cursor after the contents. If I press RET again, it adds a newline. This is a safety measure: editing text in invisible regions would be dangerous, since you can't see what you are doing. In earlier versions of Org mode, there were complaints because ...

Comment: ... people lost text that way.

Comment: org-version is 9.6.6. position is end of buffer. And RET runs the command org-return. When I press Return, I can see the line count increasing in the info bar. But the cursor stays where it is. On Reddit, someone suggested `RET-s` as the new workflow, and that indeed works similarly to before.

Comment: @Alexis5814 I suggest to post working solution as an answer. I'm too on 9.6.6. and had the described issue. In my case, `s-RET` is not defined, but on hitting `M-RET` (bound to `M-x org-meta-return`), the section is unfolded which allows to insert a new line.